# How to query multiple sheets and merge the data?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have 15 sheets that use the same template, for 15 different users. I would like to make a query on all the sheets, and display the result in a separate sheet:

```
=QUERY(Mona!A3:U300; "select A, D where C != ''")
```

Where `Mona` is the name of 1 of the 15 sheets.

So what I need is to make this QUERY on all the sheets and show the result. The columns (A,D) should only occur once.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't solve the merge part of your problem, but an efficient way of querying all the sheets is:

```
=QUERY(Indirect(A1); "select A, D where C != ''")
```

where cell `A1` has the text value `Mona!A3:U300`

With this method you can list the different sheet names in cells and have a lookup for each one.

It might be possible to use an `ArrayFormula` to combine the queries into one formula, though I'm not sure how well query would work for this - using either `Sumproduct` or `Filter` to look up values using multiple criteria might work better.

Answer (score 9):

Let me else suggest using `{}` to collect all data:

Sample formula for 3 sheets:

```
=QUERY({'1'!A1:D13;'2'!A2:D13;'3'!A2:D13},"select Col1, Col2")
```

Here we use header only once in worksheet #1: range `'1'!A1:D13` contains header, range `'2'!A2:D13` and others don't. Also we replace A, B, C notation with Col1, Col2, Col3...

Look at [example workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/154-vznuoNS7QIZG6sKoj7UP7QnYSy3BYhWtUQwNFfGQ/edit?usp=sharing), may be someone'll find it hefpful.